# Star Schema database for NBA/Basketball statistics

Tags: mysql, sql, database, relational-database, star-schema

I want to design a database of basketball players and their stats. I hear star schema databases are the best for these type of tasks.

If I'm not mistaken, star schema has dim and fact tables.

I plan to load scores/stats into the fact tables and teams,year, coach, conference, etc in the dim tables. Is this an acceptable approach?

Im a noobie at database design so please help if you can or give me your thoughts on my process. Thanks!

Comment: A fact table represents a process or event that you want to analyze. You can have multiple fact tables.

So the question is, what is the process or event that you want to analyze?

Comment: I want to be able to show stats(points, assists, rebounds, blocks, steals, etc) for each player. If understood you correctly, you suggestI have a fact table for each type of stat? ex. one for points, one for assists, etc

Comment: It depends on the grain of your analysis. Are you analyzing by play? possession? game?

Comment: by game. I want to be able to look up the avg points per game,assist per game, steals per game for any given player at any given year

Comment: Not sure if you're still interested in doing this, but I have designed a schema that scrapes nba.com and populates player data associated with teams so you can analyze information granularly (i'm still learning queries in ruby on rails so that's taking a while)